# devenv command line option for macros and lib file

Tags: devenv

I am trying to make build using devenv.exe command line and have some preprocessor definitions and lib file to be given with command line.

as such one way is to set in proj file

**c/c++ ---> proprocessor --> preposessor defintions**

i want to give macro name in command line with devenv.exe

similarly i have one additional linker library dependency

**linker - input - additional dependencies**

which i want to supply with devenv

any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

also i need the answer to solve the same question.

i have the same project source code, but different binary version will be built out with different building macros. now i try two ways to build the project. one is described as sachinc's; another is to replace the PreprocessorDefinitions in .vcproj by python scripts.

iam also hankeringly to know how to make build using devenv.exe with command line.